# Automapper: Conditionally changing value of item in list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a list that I get from a database, I want to map that to another class and get the result. However, one of the items of that list (`ContractTitle`) has its own properties (`ContractTitle.Buyer` or `ContractTitle.Seller` which are strings). For the mapped result, I want to change the value of each `ContractTitle` to either `ContractTitle.Buyer` or `ContractTitle.Seller`.

The example below is what I am attempting to do, I don't really know how to proceed though. I feel I would need a custom resolver to actually achieve this. Sorry, I am very new to automapper, find the documentation a bit confusing. Thanks!

```
IEnumerable < Document > document; //=some data from db
var condition = true

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateMap < Document, Contract > ()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ContractTitle, opt => opt
        .MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => context
            .Options.Items["ContractTitle"]))

    .ForMember(dest => dest.ContractTemplateId, opt => opt
        .MapFrom(x => x.DocumentTemplateId))

    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt
        .MapFrom(x => x.Id)));

configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
IMapper mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

if (condition) {
    return mapper.Map < IEnumerable < Contract >> (document, opt => opt
        .Items["ContractTitle"] = document.ContractTitle.Buyer);
} else {
    return mapper.Map < IEnumerable < Contract >> (document, opt => opt
        .Items["ContractTitle"] = document.ContractTitle.Seller);
}
```

Comment: Are you not getting the results you wanted? What is the output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: The code in the map does not work. document is a enumerable, i'm not able to access it like this. Or at least not this way. Here:`.Items["ContractTitle"] = document.ContractTitle.Seller);`
The output is an error saying IEnumerable<Document> does not contain ContractTitle.

Comment: As far as i understood you are mapping from a Document to a Contract. Could you please share the models Document and Contract?

Also, you could use linq to solve the condition: 

.MapFrom(src => condition ? src.ContractTitle.Buyer : src.ContractTitle.Seller)

Comment: Any library must simplify life. In this case, AutoMapper complicates it. Just throw it out and write the mapping code by simply assigning properties from one type to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the internal data that needs to be mapped into the map operation, it would probably be a better idea to pass in the condition itself, and let the mapper pick one or the other based on it while mapping each member individually:

```cs
IEnumerable < Document > document; //=some data from db
var condition = true

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateMap<Document, Contract>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ContractTitle, opt => opt
        .MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => 
            ((bool)context.Options.Items["Condition"])
                ? src.ContractTitle.Buyer
                : src.ContractTitle.Seller))

    .ForMember(dest => dest.ContractTemplateId, opt => opt
        .MapFrom(x => x.DocumentTemplateId))

    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt
        .MapFrom(x => x.Id)));

configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
IMapper mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Contract>> (document, opt => opt
        .Items["Condition"] = condition);
```